# Mixed Timed Data

Tags: r, time, time-series, data-manipulation

I have a vector that contains time data, but there's a problem: some of the entries are listed as dates (e.g., 10/11/2017), while other entries are listed as dates **with** time (e.g., 12/15/2016 09:07:17).  This is problematic for myself, since as.Date() can't recognize the time portion and enters dates in an odd format (0012-01-20), while seemingly adding dates with time entries as NA's.  Furthermore, using as.POSIXct() doesn't work, since not all entries are a combination of date with time.

I suspect that, since these entries are entered in a consistent format, I could hypothetically use an if function to change the entries in the vector to a consistent format, such as using an if statement to remove time entirely, but I don't know enough about it to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
library(lubridate)
```

Name of the data frame or table-> x
the column that has date->Date
use the ymd function

```
x$newdate<-ydm(x$Date)
```